# Adding rendered entity as an option for entity embed

Tags: drupal, entity

I'm currently experimenting and configuring the entity embed module which I have just installed recently on `Drupal 8`. On the configuration, I do not see a checkbox to "Rendered Entity" as an option(***see screenshot below***). How can I enable the option "Rendered Option" on configuration? I have browse and search everywhere but I cannot seem to find a way to enable it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `/admin/structure/display-modes/view` and add new view mode for your media entity.

Go to `/admin/structure/media/manage/{YOUR-MEDIA-TYPE}/display` and enable newly added view mode in the **Custom display settings** section.

[image]

Then switch to this new view mode and configure fields you want to output.

Once done you will be able to use it WYSIWYG:
[image]

Refer to [D8 Media Guide](https://drupal-media.gitbooks.io/drupal8-guide/content/modules/media_entity/create_view_mode.html) on how to configure an additional view mode in case I've miss something.

UPD: Adding button settings:
[image]

Comment: Hi, on the third screenshot I can't seem to figure out how I can select or get the custom view mode I just created. What is your configuration for the embed entity button

Comment: Found out I need to refresh the cache